# driver.page_source isn't taking entire html codes

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to make 'Google Patent Crawler' by using python.

I used modules like Requests, BS4, and Selenium, But I am totally stuck on one thing.

The problem is my code is not parsing entire html sources. something is missing after parsing.

I found the error from 'driver.page_source'

It is not parsing all html.

So I wanna ask about another good way to solve it.

Thank you.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_driver_path = 'C:/Users/Kay/Documents/Python/Driver/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

URL = 'https://patents.google.com/?q=engine'
driver.get(URL)
html = driver.page_source
gp_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
```

Comment: Without website no buddy can tell you that what it causing to not get page source entirely.

Comment: @Dev Thank you. it is http://patents.google.com

Comment: I think your problem has somthing to do with lazyloading. Maybe it helps to have a `time.sleep(10) ` somewhere in your code.

Comment: first describe what element it doesn't get. Maybe you don't get it from server. So first display `driver.page_source` to see what you really get from server and see if this element exists in HTML. If page uses JavaScript to add element then you may have to wait short time. If page adds elements when you scroll page then you have to use JavaScript code to scroll page. If page displays element in `<iframe>` then you have to use `drive.switch_to.frame()` to get it.

Comment: BTW: if you see expected element when you display `page_source` then you can try different engine in `BeautifulSoup` instead of `html5lib` because sometimes they work in different way.

Comment: BTW: first run code without `--headless` to see what you get from server - some server may recognize `Selenium` and block requests or send warning or captcha.